# OutOfMemoryException when merging multiple tiff files of huge sizes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, memory-management, out-of-memory

I am trying to **merge multiple image (.tiff/.tif) files into a single image(.tif)** before sending a Zip file (containing such multiple merged tif images) to AWS S3 bucket.

I have restriction of each zip file not exceeding 5GB size.

I have a scenario where **i am merging thousands of multipage tiff images into a single tiff image**.

Using `Bitmap` **i am adding each tiff image incrementally to its previous image and saving the image**.

However, i am doing it **by reading all the bytes into the** `MemoryStream`. That is where i am **facing an OutOfMemory** issue.

***When the merged image reaches a threshold size i.e. 2GB(aprox) it becomes impossible to read the bytes into a stream and then append the next image. This throws OutOfMemoryException***. I understand that this is because of the CPU RAM limitations.

But is there a better way to solve this problem of mine?

Please find my code below.

```
private void MergeTiffFiles(string filePathWithFileName) {
 string[] sa;
 sa = Directory.GetFiles(filePathWithFileName.Substring(0, filePathWithFileName.LastIndexOf('.')));
 DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(filePathWithFileName);
 long totalTiffs = di.GetFiles("*.tif").Length;

 //get the codec for tiff files
 ImageCodecInfo info = null;

 foreach(ImageCodecInfo ice in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders())
 if (ice.MimeType == "image/tiff")
  info = ice;

 //use the save encoder
 Encoder enc = Encoder.SaveFlag;

 EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters(1);
 ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long) EncoderValue.MultiFrame);

 Bitmap pages = null;

 int frame = 0;

 foreach(string s in sa) {
  if (Path.GetExtension(s) == ".tif" || Path.GetExtension(s) == ".tiff") {
   if (frame == 0) {
    **MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine("somepath\\test_sample_zip", s)));**
    pages = (Bitmap) Image.FromStream(ms);

    var appDataPath = @ "somepath\\Desktop\\";
    var filePath = Path.Combine(appDataPath, Path.GetRandomFileName() + ".tif");

    //save the first frame
    pages.Save(filePath, info, ep);

    //Save the second frame if any
    int frameCount1 = pages.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
    if (frameCount1 > 1) {
     for (int i = 1; i < frameCount1; i++) {
      ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long) EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);
      pages.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, i);
      pages.SaveAdd(pages, ep);
     }
    }
   } else if (frame < totalTiffs - 1) {
    //save the intermediate frames
    ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long) EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);
    try {
     MemoryStream mss = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine("somepath\\Desktop\\test_sample_zip", s)));
     Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) Image.FromStream(mss);
     int frameCount = bm.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
     for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
      bm.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, i);
      pages.SaveAdd(bm, ep);
     }
    } catch (Exception e) {
     //LogError(e, s);
    }
   }

   if (frame == totalTiffs - 1) {
    //flush and close.
    ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long) EncoderValue.Flush);
    pages.SaveAdd(ep);

   }

   frame++;
  }
 }
}
```

The code works fine upto a particular size as long as the RAM free memory doesn't run out.

The line which throws the exception is

**`MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine("somepath\\test_sample_zip", s)));**`

May be merging the tiff images without having to read them into `MemoryStream` would be the best solution for my problem, but have no clue on how that can be done.

Or if there are any third party software which merge tiff images.

Comment: You are probably hitting the 2GB limit for a file in GDI+. Perhaps you could make use of the [.NET library for ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the cause of the OutOfMemoryException, but TIFF files have a maximium limit of about 2 to 4 GB depending on the implementation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF

> The TIFF file formats use 32-bit offsets, which limits file size to around 4 GiB. Some implementations even use a signed 32-bit offset, running into issues around 2 GiB already.

Answer (score 0):

If something is Disposable, you should always Dispose it. It will eventually get cleaned up by the garbage collector itself, but it is always good practice to call Dispose.

You should dispose the memorystream object before the next iteration, most probably this should solve your issue also.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine("somepath\\test_sample_zip", s)))) {
...
...
}
ms.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a `FileStream` instead of a `MemoryStream`?

Instead of

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine("somepath\\test_sample_zip", s)));
pages = (Bitmap) Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Try

```
Stream m = File.OpenRead(Path.Combine("somepath\\test_sample_zip", s));
pages = (Bitmap) Image.FromStream(m);
```